# Github search by created

Tags: curl, github-api

I am using the following [link](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#rate-limit) to search using curl. My intention is to get results which are sorted by creation.

My sample query is as follows:

```
curl 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=arrow&sort=created' > results.txt
```

When I search the 'results.txt', I get results which are not ordered by creation dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`created` is not a sort order, but a [search qualifier, a filter](https://help.github.com/articles/search-syntax/).

You would use it as part of the `q` parameter:

[`cats created:>=2012-04-30`](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=cats%20created%3A%3E%3D2012-04-30&type=Issues)

```
https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=cats+created%3A%3E%3D2012-04-30&type=Issues
```

The sort order only involve  `stars`, `forks`, or `updated`.
Not creation date.

Comment: Thanks. So how do I sort using the API. Becaase I need the json

Comment: @EchchamaNayak I don't see a sort order by creation date: I have edited the answer.

Comment: @EchchamaNayak Once you have the json result, you need another tool to sort it according to the field you want.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't found anything related to limits. Can they be applied in the URL?

Comment: @EchchamaNayak By "limits", you mean the number of results returned? or the date range?

Comment: number or results

Comment: @EchchamaNayak Then you need to use pagination: https://developer.github.com/guides/traversing-with-pagination/. The url can include a "`&per_page=50`" parameter for instance.

Answer (score 0):

When you take a look at the documentation you can see that `sort` specified options like `stars`, `forks` and `updated`

https://developer.github.com/v3/search/

To get the created you have to define them in your filter then its an defined word in the filter. You can see that in the documentation.